# Unzoom pictures in PHP

Tags: php, image-scaling

Let's say I have a 200x100px picture. Is there any PHP function or PHP library function that can unzoom such a picture?

So I would call something like:

```
    $new_picture = unzoom($picture, $percentage);
   // and the new picture will be smaller based on $percentage
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean by unzoom? do you want to resize pictures??

Comment: Have you tried anything ? You can refer this http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Comment: 200x100px is very small to start with???  Although I guess maybe you want to create a thumbnail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several options:

- [`imagecopyresampled()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) using GD
- [`Imagick::resizeImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-resizeimage.php) using ImageMagick
- Cairo, Gmagick

See also: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.utilspec.image.php